# Finding the ID of a checkbox and single selection in a child gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wanted to find the ID of a checkbox and only single select one of multiple checkboxes. I don't want to  use radio buttons though.

**Here's what I did so far to find the ID of the checkboxes :**

```
protected void gvChild_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvParent.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    GridView gvChild = (GridView)row.FindControl("gvChild");
                    // Then do the same method for check box column 
                    if (gvChild != null)
                    {
                        foreach (GridViewRow rowChild in gvChild.Rows)
                        {
                            if (rowChild.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                            {
                                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)rowChild.FindControl("CbList");
                                if (chk.Checked)
                                {
                                    string strScript = "uncheckOthers(" + ((CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("CbList")).ClientID + ");";
                                    ((CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("CbList")).Attributes.Add("onclick", strScript);
                                    testLabel.Text = strScript;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I use "uncheckOthers()" as my javascript function to single select one and only checkbox.

NOTE : This function works properly in a parent gridview.

**Here's the code to that function :**

```
function uncheckOthers(id) {
    var elm = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < elm.length; i++) {
        if (elm.item(i).id.substring(id.id.lastIndexOf('_')) == id.id.substring(id.id.lastIndexOf('_'))) {
            if (elm.item(i).type == "checkbox" && elm.item(i) != id)
                elm.item(i).checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Last , but not least the Markup (removed boundfields for security purposes):**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvParent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="list" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvParent_SelectedIndexChanged" DataKeyNames="MoodleTemplateID">
                    <Columns>
                        
                        <asp:TemplateField>

                            <ItemTemplate>
                             
                            <img alt="" src="Images/view16x16.png"/>
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlChild" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvChild" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass = "list" DataKeyNames="ID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvChild_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDataBound="gvChild_RowDataBound">
                                
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                
                                <ItemTemplate>                              

                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CbList" runat="server"/>                    

                                </ItemTemplate>
                                
                                <HeaderStyle Width="20px" />
                                
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        
                                     <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" SelectImageUrl="Images/edit16x16.png" ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Editar">
                                
                                <ItemStyle Width="10px" />
                            
                            </asp:CommandField>            
                                    
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Editar">
                                
                                <ItemStyle Width="10px" />
                            
                            </asp:CommandField> 

                       
                    </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: That logic not  going to work. Say 5 child choices. Choice 2 is checked. If I now check choice 5, then you run your loop, and when you find the first one checked, then you un-check all. So now the 2nd one will remain checked!!! If you are willing to use a post-back for that check box, then you don't even need to loop the parent grid, but could simply get the ID of checked, and then un-check all other rows in that child grid. I'll post solution but only if checkbox doing post-back and auto postback = true is ok for you. (if not, then my idea is of little value).

Comment: Yes , that actually makes sense. However , I have a feature that collapses and expands the child gridview when clicking a button. Then if I check a checkbox and auto post back is true, in the child grid it will return to its original state which is "collapsed" and that can't happen.

Comment: Hum, my experience is that the grid and expanded child grid will not colipase on post-back. (the state of both gv's should remains ok as long as you not re-binding the grid on that post back.  I can post a example - I often use a listview for the parent grid, since it supports "spans" better then using two nested gv's. I'll post my working example in a bit.

Comment: Hum , okay! I'll give it a shot with your solution. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: ok, posted - note that we could drop the whole mess (the lv) inside of a update panel if other parts of the page can't handle or don't want a full page post back. Work your way through how it works - it not too much code, but it is all server side code. I suppose making this work client side would be nice, but it not a big deal. I mean, if I was to start writing a lot of JavaScript, then yes, it would be "better" response, but so far this approach is still responsive enough.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first up, I am going to suggest that the main grid is a list view.

The reason is listview supports "span" a lot better. When I try to nest gv's, they tend to look like this:

[image]

But, nesting the gridview inside of a listview, then it works much better like this:

[image]

And really amazing, is that without extra code the expanded parts persist - without really any extra code.

So here is our markup - and I added a check box to the child gv in above.

```
  <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" >
       <ItemTemplate>
          <tr style="">
            <td><asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="+" OnClick="cmdView_Click" /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="HotelNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="CityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="ProvinceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Province") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' /></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
               <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                 DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" style="display:none"  >
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Firstname" HeaderText="Firstname"  />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"  />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox id="ckSel" runat="server" 
                                  OnCheckedChanged="ckSel_CheckedChanged"
                                  AutoPostBack="true" >
                               </asp:CheckBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </td>
           </tr>
           </ItemTemplate>

       <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" Class = "table table-hover" >
            <tr runat="server" style="">
                <th runat="server">View</th>
                <th runat="server">HotelName</th>
                <th runat="server">City</th>
                <th runat="server">Province</th>
                <th runat="server">Description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
            </tr>
         </table>
       </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Ok, so here is our load up the grid (well, I used listview).

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    public void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM tblHotels WHERE ID in (select hotel_Id from People)
                        ORDER BY HotelName";

        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL,
            new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            ListView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Ok, so run the above, and we get this:

[image]

Ok, now next bus stop is the + key. This is just a plane jane regular asp.net button. And I DID NOT bother with gridview or the listview built in events (selected index and all that jazzz - its too confusing and better yet we just don't care nor need to bother with the events of those gv, or lv's.

Ok, so our code is this:
not too much!!!

```
    protected void cmdView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button cmd = (Button)sender;
        ListViewDataItem gVR = (ListViewDataItem)cmd.Parent;
        GridView gChild = (GridView)gVR.FindControl("GridView2");   // pluck out the grid for this row

        if (gChild.Style["display"] == "normal")
        {
            // if grid is already display, then hide it, and exit
            gChild.Style["display"] = "none";
            return;
        }
        gChild.Style["display"] = "normal";
        string HotelPK = (string)ListView1.DataKeys[gVR.DataItemIndex]["ID"];

        // only re-load if never loaded (can't re-load else blow out check boxes

        if (gChild.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            string strSQL = @"SELECT * from People where hotel_id = " + HotelPK;
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL,
                new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4)))
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
                gChild.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
                gChild.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Ok, so that will expand, colipase each row. and REALLY amazing is that state management works (it remembers the expand or collapse - and it WILL even remember the setting of the un-bound check box.

So, we expand say the first row. We get this:

[image]

Ok, so now the only part left is the checkbox click event. and again, not too much code:

```
    protected void ckSel_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox ckBox = (CheckBox)sender;

        GridView gvChild = (GridView)ckBox.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent;
        GridViewRow gvRowClick = (GridViewRow)ckBox.Parent.Parent;
        if (ckBox.Checked)
        {
            // user just checked this box - un-check all
            foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gvChild.Rows)
            {
                if (gvRow.RowIndex != gvRowClick.RowIndex)
                {
                    CheckBox ckRowBox = (CheckBox)gvRow.FindControl("ckSel");
                    ckRowBox.Checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

A few things:

As noted, I dumped use of the gridv/listv event model. (we just pick up the grid view/listview row using sender.parent.

And we don't load the child grids until expanded - this is good for performance.

and if it been expanded, and we click "+" again, we hide, but if we re-expand, then we don't hit the database to re-load (and we don't want to, since if we did, then the checkbox would be lost).

And quite amazing? the lv/gv does retain its state for us. So expanded parts even survice the checkbox post back code.

I did not write out back to the database, but it would be quite simple code to then process each list-view row, then get the gv, and then get the checked row (PK ID) and then write that back to the database or do whatever if we wanted to on some button outside of this lv/gv.

Comment: I decided to keep both of my gridviews , the event checkedchanged worked like a charm, but as I expected with autopostback="true" the child gridview collapses instantly and you said it yourself that if I rebind on that postback it will surely changed to its original state which is "collapsed", I'm rebinding in an event called OnRowDataBound() , do I really need to change it to a button then in the OnClick Event I do the DataBind() what's my other option here? Thank you very much.

Comment: I found a bug in your code , if you expand all of the views and you check one checkbox in that and if you expand another view and check another checkbox the checkbox of the previous view won't uncheck.

Comment: It works for me, and I don't see that issue. Does the only allow of one check box work for you? You do NOT re-bind EVER except on first page load (but then again 99% of any code will ONLY ever work that way anyway). Note how in my example the check box is un-bound (it does not have a expression that sets the text box. There is no reason to re-bind anything more then you need to. in my example, if I expand a group, then I am free to check one box. If I check another then the other is un-checked. As for re-binding on row databound? Well, sure, then you don't need the bind code I have on expand.

Comment: If the childs are already bound? Then of course you don't have to bind + fill child grid on expand. So, assuming you removed the bind on the expand click button? Don't see why it would not work. I don't load child grid until you click, else you pulling data when you don't need to. But it should not matter. So if you bind child gv's on parent bind via row data bind? Should still work. So that means that when you click to expand, or click on a check box after expand? You DO NOT re-bind that child grid and you don't have to. If you re-bind, then you lose check box settings for sure.

Comment: And no, my expanded grids do not collapse on post back. This means your page load is re-loading the grid, or re-binding - it should not (and ANY page you EVER have should not unless for some good reason. If you re-bind on post-back? Why then of course the expanded parts will collapse, and row data bound re-fires and will blow out any checkboxes. But, then again, on post backs, you are re-binding the gv, and you should not be. There is ZERO reason to cause a re-bind on any post back. So check that. If you don't re-bind, then the grid and expanded parts and ckbox will survive post-back

Comment: So you can probably keep your command and selected index fire event I don't mess with that extra complex. If u bind child gv's on row data bind (from parent). Then the expand button of course cannot re-bind child gv's and does not have to. So binding the parent one time will let row data bind event fill chiild gv's. Your grid and child grids are full bound and filled. From onwards, then no reason exists to re-bind anything at all. If you don't re-bind, then a simple expand will remain expand. I can expand 1 or 3 sections - check a box and the 3 sections remain expanded in and displayed.

Comment: Oh my god , I finally managed to do it! Thank you very much , you're really a lifesaver.

Comment: That is great. So the expand button only sets style="display:normal" or display:none. And as you see it should persist.  So in effect the data bind code in the expand button now goes and is moved to the row data bound of main gv, and thus not required in the expand button.  This issue of avoiding re-binds is a great tip . We can't always avoid this issue - and if you need a datapager - then you are probaby screwed, since pagers have to re-bind the grid. In that case? Then you would have to set checkbox (eval()) during binding, and on click update the database to hold the checkbox status.

Comment: Yes , I studied your code almost line by line and I got that part. The part that was messing up the whole thing was the re-binds just like you said.

Comment: Great. And for that .parent.parent.parent code? I actually use a function to do that for me, since a extra div or whatever can cause you to need a extra .parent. So I have a tiny function that does that for me. Now you can still use the "commandName" and use selected index changed - but I often find just using a event stub and using .parent to get the gv, or gv "row" is easier. Good luck!

Comment: And by the way - I never did get two gv's nesting very well as my first screen shot shows - so I used LV for the main grid - it don't matter - too busy right now, but am curious as to how well, or in fact how you made 2 gv's behave nice. - no worries - what works is what works.

Comment: So what I made to behave nicely was using some JQuery, in that way I also changed the button to "minus" when expanded and "plus" when collapsed.

Comment: Yes, the + expand key is a good example for js code. Since you moved the fill of child grids to you row databound, then the +/- key only has to set that style - and that will be very snappy and without a post-back to hide/show the child grid(s).